# Magento 2.2 error when tried to load product or order in external file

Tags: magento2, product, collection, external

I tried to load a product or an order form an external file using Object Manager but everytime i receive the same err: 
"`PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException: Requested store is not found in ..."`

[image]

My code:

```
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$params = $_SERVER;
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
```

and then i tried to load my order :

`$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderID);` or product

```
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
```

Does anyone know why i receive this err?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');
```